# C file never found

Tags: c, sockets, server

I'm making a socket server that will for example take using input like "localhost:8080/WWW/index.html" and it will return the index.html file. I'm able to parse the request so that when someone inputs that I will have a buffer of "/WWW/index.html" and from the location of my program if I did vim /WWW/index.html I would open if but for some reason my code always says that the file is not found. Here is the following code...

```
char* parseRequest(char* request) {
  //assume file paths are no more than 256 bytes + 1 for null. 
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*257);
  memset(buffer, 0, 257);

  if(fnmatch("GET * HTTP/1.*",  request, 0)) return 0;

  sscanf(request, "GET %s HTTP/1.", buffer);
  return buffer;
}

int fileExists(const char *fname){
        FILE *file;
        if(file = fopen(fname, "r"))
        {
                fclose(file);
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}


        recv(sock,buffer,255,0);
        //reading inputted directory
        char *dir = parseRequest(buffer);
        if(fileExists(dir) == 1){
                send(sock, "File found", 200, 0);
        }else{
                send(sock, "404: File not found", 200, 0);
        }
```

Comment: the posted code is trying to access, for read, a web page: index.html.  Unless the server is very sloppily setup, the server should deny the client access to reading the index.html file.  There is a specific area, usually/should setup, in the server where a client is allowed to access files.  All other directories/files should be setup with 'deny' privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Where `dir` is equal to "/WWW/index.html"**

```
#define MAXBUF 256
#define DOCUMENTS_ROOT "/home/longbear/hw4"

char path[MAXBUF] = DOCUMENTS_ROOT;
strcat(path, dir);
```

.
.
.

**Now** *you should be able to open the file at `path`.*

Comment: Ok these may be helpful in the future once I can open the files themselves but I don't see how this would help me open those files or check if they exist.

Comment: Ah, ok I already tried doing the full paths. Before the server would look at ~/hw4/WWW/index.html instead of just /WWW/index.html, but this did not help the problem. I concatenated "~/hw4" and "/WWW/index.html" strings together to achieve this

Comment: Path to index.html.. I will find that out in a sec

Comment: /home/longbear/hw4/WWW/index.html

Comment: Well then you have to concatenate '/home/longbear/hw4' to '/WWW/index.html' to find the file.

Comment: Ok I will try that but I think /home/longbear/hw4 is the same as ~/hw4, I will try right now tho

Comment: the path looks like a *inx OS.  the client will not be able to do anything with the index.html file unless that file as the appropriate permissions (which it should not) and the server setup allows reading the web page source files, which it should not